# SSIS error: The Password was not allowed

Tags: ssis

I am receiving the following error when executing the FTP task in SSIS.

```
The Password was not allowed
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSIS saves sensitive data (like passwords) encrypted based on the value of the `ProtectionLevel` package property. This value is `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` by default (this means, that the encrypted part could be read with the same user account which created the package). Learn more about [Access Control on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747(v=sql.110).aspx)

You can set this property to `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`, then set the `PackagePassword` property. You can execute the package with DTExec utility with the `/De {password}` parameter.
(You can edit package properties by right clicking on a blank area on the package's control flow, then selecting Properties item).

Another way is to set up a simple `Script Task` (before the `FTP Task`) which sets the value at runtime. The following code sets the password property of the `FTPConnectionName` connection.

*C# code*

```
ConnectionManager FTPConn;
FTPConn = Dts.Connections["FTPConnectionName"];
FTPConn.Properties["ServerPassword"].SetValue(FTPConn, "YourPassword");
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Add this code to the script task's entry point (Main() function).
(Optionally you can add a string variable to your package and add it to the Read Only variables of the script task and use it (`Dts.Variables["FTPPassword"].Value`) to set the password.